# How to download entire folder of blobs (images) from google storage bucket to AI Platform Notebooks in one go?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-storage, blob, gsutil

I am new to GCP, so thank you in advance for your patience. I have uploaded a folder, which contains folders, which contain images, to my google cloud storage bucket, and now I want to train a model that uses that data on an AI platform instance of jupyter notebooks. I have been able to download individual blobs without a problem, but when it's time to download the entire folder of image data I need, the folder is not recognized (I understand it's not a blob, but I still need the data locally on jupyter lab to efficiently train the model, right?). I have seen FUSE is not an option because of cost. I'm guessing there's a way to do this inside the GCP environment, but I haven't been able to figure it out. Again, thanks for your help!

Edit:

Here's the code that (understandably) gives me an error:

```
blob_name = "five_gestures/"
blob = bucket.get_blob(blob_name)

output_file_name = "gestures/"
blob.download_to_filename(output_file_name)

print("Downloaded blob {} to {}.".format(blob.name, output_file_name))
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-9de8423ff843> in <module>
      3 
      4 output_file_name = "gestures/"
----> 5 blob.download_to_filename(output_file_name)
      6 
      7 print("Downloaded blob {} to {}.".format(blob.name, output_file_name))

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'download_to_filename'
```

And an example of the path to a single image is:

five_gestures/00/01_palm/frame_00_01_0001.png

And 01_palm containing hundreds of those images.

Comment: show your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to first list all the files in a directory and then download them one by one:

```
bucket_name = 'your-bucket-name'
prefix = 'your-bucket-directory/'
dl_dir = 'your-local-directory/'

storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
blobs = bucket.list_blobs(prefix=prefix)  # Get list of files
for blob in blobs:
    filename = blob.name.replace('/', '_') 
    blob.download_to_filename(dl_dir + filename)  # Download
```

`blob.name` includes the entire directory structure + filename, so if you want the same file name as in the bucket, you might want to extract it first (instead of replacing `/` with `_`)